# Sharepoint - How to: dynamic Url for Note on Noteboard

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm quite new to SharePoint (about 1 week into it actually) and I'm attempting to mirror certain functionality that my company has with other products.  Currently I'm working on how to duplicate the tasking environment in Box.com.  Essentially it's just an email link that goes to a webpage where users can view an image and comments related to that image side by side.

I can dynamically load the image based on url parameters using just Javascript so that part is not a problem.  As far as the comments part goes I've been trying to use a Noteboard WebPart, and then my desire is to have the "Url for Note" property to change dependent on the same URL parameter.  I've looked over the Javascript Object Model and Class Library on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185006%28v=office.14%29.aspx) but the hierarchy seems to stop at WebPart so I'm not finding anything that will allow me to update the Url for Note property.

I've read comments saying that there's a lot of exploration involved with this so I've tried the following:

-loading the javascript files into VisualStudio to use intellisense for looking up functions and properties in the SP.js files.

-`console.log()` on: WebPartDefinitionCollection, WebPartDefinition, WebPart, and methods `.get_objectData()`, `get_properties()` on all the previous

-embedding script in the "Builder" on the Url for Note property (where it says "click to use Builder" - I'm still not sure what more this offers than just a bigger textbox to put in the URL path)

I'm certain I've missed something obvious here but am gaining information very slowly now that I've exhausted the usual suspects.  I very much appreciate any more resources or information anyone has and am willing to accept that I may be approaching this incorrectly if someone has accomplished this before.

Normally I'd keep going through whatever info I could find but I'm currently on a trial period and start school back up again soon so I won't have as much time with it.  Apologies if this seems impatient, I'm just not sure where else to look at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out the API libraries like [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) or [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/)? They could help you doing what you want...

For example with SharepointPlus you could:

1. Create a Sharepoint List with a "Note" column and whatever you need to record
2. When the user goes to the page with the image you just show a TEXTAREA input with a SAVE button
3. When the user hits the SAVE button it will save the Note to the related list using `$SP().list("Your list").add()`
4. And you can easily retrieve the information (to show them to the user if he goes back to the page) with `$SP().list("Your list").get()`

If I understood your problem, that way it may be easier for you to deal with a customized page :-)

Comment: No I had only been looking at the OOTB features.  I'll give this a look, thanks!